# Why does the anchor of the InfoWindows (Maps API V2) is so badly displayed?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a very simple question, with really basic code that really annoys me.

I am just trying to display a dimple info windows on my map with this code:

```
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(aTraffic.getLat(), aTraffic.getLon()))
            .title(aTraffic.getCategory())
            .anchor(0.0f, 0.0f)// I tried to remove this line, but does not change anything...
            .snippet(aTraffic.getMessage())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_c_traffic)));
```

But it looks like the Dialog is really badly displayed: the anchor is way on the jeft side of the icon

Any idea what I am droing wrong or what I should do to fix that?

[image]

Comment: I guess the icon of the marker is the blue cone, right?

Comment: Yes, I heven't mentionned that, this is indeed the icon, and it perectly square drwable with 48*48 px resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this issue should be closed or deleted, but I have found this as a reported bug on the Maps API bug tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5439

and this entry leads to some duplicate on StackOverflow.